# What would happen if I delete/replace the shared library after it has been explicit loaded with dlopen()?

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

What would happen if I delete/replace the shared library after it has been explicit loaded with dlopen() ?

Does dlopen() load the entire shared library into memory ?
Or in the long run, the dlopen() has to refer the previously loaded library which reside in the filesystem, from time to time.
If so, how do I enforce the dlopen() load the whole .so to memory ?

Does flag RTLD_NOW means to load entire library into memory ?

Comment: This is really a question about `mmap`. If you do a "proper" install (write to a new file, then rename), then the inode remains accessible until nobody else is using it. If you try to write to the file directly, you get `ETXTBSY` (note that the man page is misleading).

Comment: Actually, it looks like only executables get `ETXTBUSY`; libraries just lead to weird crashes.

Answer (score 3):

> What would happen if I delete/replace the shared library after it has been explicit loaded with dlopen() ?

It you *delete* and then write a new file with the same name, nothing bad will happen. But if you *overwrite* existing file, you will likely see strange crashes.

> Does dlopen() load the entire shared library into memory ?

No. It simply `mmap`s it into memory. Unless you use `mlock` over the code and data of the library, it will be [demand-paged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) from disk.

> Does flag `RTLD_NOW` means to load entire library into memory ?

Not at all. `RTLD_NOW` is pretty irrelevant to your question, and does not help.

---

So why is there a difference between `unlink`+`write` vs. `write` over existing data?

On UNIX removing (via `unlink` system call) a file does not actually remove it from disk -- the data remains on disk until all *references* to the file are gone. An open file descriptor constitutes such a reference, and so does existing `mmap`.

But if you *overwrite* existing file which has already been `mmap`ed, demand-paging may bring the *new* contents from disk, likely with disastrous results.

P.S. As o11c noted, overwriting the file that is `mmap`ed may fail with `ETXTBUSY`, though this depends on the OS and filesystem.

Comment: Citation needed. I just tried this with copying `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Actually, this is interesting: only executables have protection; libraries do not.